# How to access a file, which is on-premises, from Azure?

Tags: azure

I have a C# console application which is accessing a file on an on-premises server. If it is moved as a web job, how does the console application inside the webjob in azure access the on-premises server?

Comment: Turning this around: How would you make your on-premises server visible to the outside world? If you can answer that, you should be able to solve your problem, since there's no magic on the Azure side - it's all about how you open up your local server firewall.

Comment: So... based on my first comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow, as it's very broad - lots of ways to make a file visible from a local server. This isn't an Azure-specific issue - it's a server security/sharing issue.